# How can I save local changes that have been done in Yocto repository?

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto

I'm working on some Linux embedded system at the moment and using Yocto to build Linux distribution for a board.

I've followed Yocto build flow:

- download layers sources
- build image
- flash image into the board or generate SDK.

Everything works great. However I was required to add some changes to local.conf, probably add some *.bbapend files, systemd services and so forth.
So, I'm wondering how can I save those local changes in case if I'll want to setup a new build machine or current one will be corrupted.

Should I create a custom image or layer that will inherit everything from a board manufacturer one and add changes and functionalities that are needed to me? Or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally when working on a custom project with Yocto, here is what possibly you will need:

First of all, you need to create your custom layer

```
bitbake-layers create-layer meta-custom
```

and add it:

```
bitbake-layers add-layer <path/to/meta-custom>
```

After that, here are some ideas:

***Official recipes modification:***

When you have to modify some official recipe that exist in other official layer, you need to create a `.bbappend` file into your custom layer and make your changes there.

```
meta-official/recipes-example/example/example_1.0.bb
```

your modifications must be made under:

```
meta-custom/recipes-example/example/example_1.0.bbappend
```

or to match all versions of that recipe:

```
meta-custom/recipes-example/example/example_%.bbappend
```

***Distro modification:***

If you changed `DISTRO_FEATURES` in `local.conf` you may need to create a new distro in your new custom layer:

```
meta-custom/conf/distro/custom-distro.conf
```

in **custom-distro.conf**:

- `include` or `require` your current used distro
- Add your custom configuration `DISTRO_FEATURES`

Then, when creating new build, set (in `local.conf`):

```
DISTRO = "custom-distro"
```

Examples for distro changes:

- Select the init manager: `INIT_MANAGER = "systemd"` for example.
- Add some distro features
- Set some preferred recipes versions `PREFERRED_VERSION_recipe = "x"`
- Set some preferred providers `PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/xx = "x"`

***Machine modification:***

If your board presents a permanent hardware components that, by default, are not activated in Yocto, then I suggest to create a new custom machine as well:

```
meta-custom/conf/machine/custom-machine.conf
```

In that, `include` or `require` your current machine configuration file and you may:

- Select your preferred virtual/kernel provider
- Select your preferred virtual/bootloader provider
- Select your custom kernel and bootloader device tree files
- etc.

and then, set it (in `local.conf`):

```
MACHINE = "custom-machine"
```

***Image modification:***

This is the most probable modification one may have, which is adding some packages to the image with `IMAGE_INSTALL`, so you may need to create a custom image:

```
meta-custom/recipes-core/images/custom-image.bb
```

in that `require` or `include` other image and:

- Add packages with `IMAGE_INSTALL`

**NOTES**

- If you have `bbappend` that append to an official `bbappend` then you consider making your layer more priority to the official one in `meta-custom/conf/layer.conf`
- If your new custom layer depends on your manufacturer layer than you may consider making it depends on it in the layer conf file:

```
LAYERDEPENDS_meta-custom = "meta-official"
```

- I recommend using `kas` which you can setup an automatic layers configuration with your custom layer and create the build automatically, this is also useful for DevOps pipelines automation.

This is what I can think of right now :))

**EDIT**

You can then create a custom repository for your custom layer.

If you are using `repo` for your manufacturer provided initialization, then you can use this idea:

You can customize the manufacturer's manifest file to add your new custom repository, like the following:

Add `remote` block for your custom git server

```
<remote name="custom-git" fetch="ssh://git@gitlab.xxx/<group>/"/>
```

If your custom layer is under the git server directly remove `group` or set it if it is the case.

Then, add your custom layer as a `project`:

```
<project path="<where/to/unpack>" name="<name/under/remote>" remote="custom-git" revision="<commit>" />
```

You can check for more `repo` details [here](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/master/docs/manifest-format.md).

Finally, you just use `repo` with your custom repository/manifest:

```
repo init -u <custom-git/manifest-project> -b <branch> -m custom-project.xml
repo sync
```

Comment: And then, I should place my custom on remote repository and create a manifest file that includes layers what I need in order to use Google Repo Tool and to be able to get my layer on different machines (if needed). Is this correct?

Comment: Check my **EDIT**